# Delphi HttpRio SOAPHTTPClient does not add a prefix to namespaced variables

Tags: xml, delphi, soap, delphi-7, afas-online

I'm developing a soap service/connection to AFAS, and based on the WSDL (which is password protected), delphi generates an interface.

I can call the resulting interface using HTTPRIO and the GetConnector that it then provides me:

```
FGetAfas.GetData(FEnvironment, FUsername, FPassword, '', FConnectorID, '')
```

Function:

```
function FGetAfas(): GetConnectorSoap;
var
  HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  HTTPRIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
  with HTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode do begin
    ConnectTimeout := 60000;
    SendTimeout := 60000;
    ReceiveTimeout := 60000;
    UserName := FDomain + '\' + FUsername;
    Password := FPassword;
  end;

  Result := GetGetConnectorSoap(False, FUrl, HTTPRIO);
end;
```

The resulting soap call then looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"  xmlns:NS1="urn:Afas.Profit.Services">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <NS1:GetData xmlns:NS1="urn:Afas.Profit.Services">
      <environmentId>ab1</environmentId>
      <userId>aaa</userId>
      <password>bbb</password>
      <connectorId>1</connectorId>
    </NS1:GetData>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

However, the receiving server returns a warning that environmentId is empty. Which as you can see above, it's not.

I've figured out the issue however, it turns out that the server expects the sub-elements to be prefixed with the NS1 namespace as well. much like this: (I'll skip the body and envelope bits in this example)

```
<NS1:GetData xmlns:NS1="urn:Afas.Profit.Services">
  <NS1:environmentId>ab1</NS1:environmentId>
  <NS1:userId>aaa</NS1:userId>
  <NS1:password>bbb</NS1:password>
  <NS1:connectorId>1</NS1:connectorId>
</NS1:GetData>
```

When I put the new request in SoapUI, all works fine.

Thus we come to the question(s):

- 1: It it normal for a server to require the child elements of a namespaced element to have a namespace prefix as well?
- 2: Is there an elegant way to ensure the delphi interface attaches the namespace prefix to the values? One way would be to do a stringreplace in a HTTPRIO.OnBeforeExecute procedure,. but this does not seem a very elegant way of going about a fix.

SoapUI generates the following request when loading from the WSDL:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:urn="urn:Afas.Profit.Services">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <urn:GetData>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:environmentId>?</urn:environmentId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:userId>?</urn:userId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:password>?</urn:password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:logonAs>?</urn:logonAs>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:connectorId>?</urn:connectorId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:filtersXml>?</urn:filtersXml>
      </urn:GetData>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: First, you always need to identify which version of Delphi you are using, and whether you are using a higher version WSDL importer (you can sometimes fix problems with newer importers).

Next,what does the request look like if you generate it with SoapUI? Does it have prefixes on everything?

Comment: a bit offtopic, I see you are using the GetConnector via NTLM (=legacy). Better is to use an AppConnector (future proof). I gave up connecting to webservices with Delphi. .NET has more straightforward support for Web/WCF (FYI, I recently implemented an AFAS integration project with C#).

Comment: Yup, the soapui generated request has the namespace in front of each line. - added version tag (delphi-7), also good point on the AppConnector, I'll have to look into that later however, but thanks for the pointer. The service in question is : "https://profitweb.afasonline.nl/profitservices/getconnector.asmx"

Comment: FYI, maybe related : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20424997/800214. I know how to fix this but don't have Delphi at hand right now, will try tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at some of ours, no, it isn't normal to require namespaces on every element.  NS1 on the GetData parent node should cover you. But server implementation may vary.... you're not saying what service you're hitting.

I recommend creating a mock service with SoapUI, then change your endpoint to hit the SoapUI mock, and see if it works. If so, then the problem is with the server.  Oh you'll still have to fix your code to work with the server, but you'll have the satisfaction of being right.

Comment: Being right is always nice. Though it does cost time sadly. I may end up just having to e-mail their support to take a look at it, and just manually add the NS1 prefixes for now,. so the connection can be tested further.

Answer (score 0):

Try an updated WSDL importer. See Bruce McGee's answer in this link question:
[Delphi 2005 Web Services problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195265/delphi-2005-web-services-problem)

He references a link to D2007 WSDL Importer: http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/24535
That helped us a lot.