# SOAP WSDL Formatting (THTTPRIO)

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I'm consuming a SOAP Web Service that requires the text ":com" in some of the tags. For example instead of

```
<soapenv:Envelope >
    <soapenv:Body>
        <RunSimpleTrip>
            <c>
                <CompanyCode>CompanyCode</CompanyCode>
                <Password>Password</Password>
                <Username>Username</Username>
            </c>
            <BasicTrip>
                <Comments />
                <Driver>Some Driver</Driver>
                <EndOdometer />
                ...
            </BasicTrip>
        </RunSimpleTrip>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It needs to be

```
<soapenv:Envelope >
    <soapenv:Body>
        <RunSimpleTrip>
            <c>
                <com:CompanyCode>CompanyCode</com:CompanyCode>
                <com:Password>Password</com:Password>
                <com:Username>Username</com:Username>
            </c>
            <BasicTrip>
                <com:Comments />
                <com:Driver>Some Driver</com:Driver>
                <com:EndOdometer />
                ...
            </BasicTrip>
        </RunSimpleTrip>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Notice how not all the tags need the prefix (like the c or BasicTrip tags). Just the inner ones, the fields of the objects.

Am I stuck with doing a StringReplace on each individual tag, or is there an option I'm missing? Is there some way to toggle the importer or WSDL .pas file to do this by itself?

This is the same question, which received no good answer at the time [Delphi HttpRio SOAPHTTPClient does not add a prefix to namespaced variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004146/delphi-httprio-soaphttpclient-does-not-add-a-prefix-to-namespaced-variables) . And just like the question, when I generate this via soapUI it places the ":com" on the needed tags.

Edit: Here's a snippet of the WSDL that describes a BasicTrip

```
<xs:complexType name="BaseTrip">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="Comments" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Driver" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="EndOdometer" type="xs:decimal"/>
<xs:element name="GetMapPoints" type="xs:boolean"/>
...
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Well, `com:` is just a prefix that represents an actual namespace which should be declared as an attribute in one of the higher xml nodes like `xmlns:com="namespaceuri"`. But there should not be an requirement for the prefix to be called `com:`. Even so a good webservice should not care about prefixes at all, as long as the namespace is correctly declared using either prefixes or the namespace specification in the xml nodes themselves. Useally namespacing will be correctly set up when importing a wdsl, so it looks like the wdsl did not specify them...

Comment: It's definitely not the best web service I've seen. I've already had to make some very questionable String Replacements. I was just hoping I wouldn't have to do it for every tag. I don't have any control over the web service, and I highly doubt I have much pull with the developers.

Comment: Such a small snippet is to few for a correct analysis of the generate `.pas` in relation to that wsdl. Depending on how it was setup (imports etc) the only way to determine whether the generate pas and wsdl are correct is to completely post both...

Comment: But Delphi picks it’s own prefixes, even when the import is correct. Have you tried to actually declare the namespace prefix (using a different prefix then `com:`) and see if it works using soapui or some other tool.